# Euler constant and von Mangoldt function

Tags: number-theory

Can anyone provide a reference or link on how the following equation was derived:

$$\gamma = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1-\Lambda (k)}{k}$$

where $γ$ is Euler-Mascheroni constant, and $Λ(k)$ is von Mangoldt function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$\sum \frac{1-\Lambda(k)}{k} = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}  \sum \limits_{k \leq n} \frac{1-\Lambda(k)}{k} =  \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}  \sum \limits_{k \leq n} \frac{1}{k} - \sum \limits_{k \leq n} \frac{\Lambda(k)}{n} = H_n - \sum \limits_{p \leq n}  \frac{\ln p}{p} - \sum \limits_{p \leq n } \sum \limits_{r=2}^{\infty} \frac{\ln p}{ p^r} $

By Mertens third theorem and PNT $\sum \limits_{p \leq n} \frac{\ln p}{p} = \ln n - \gamma - \sum \limits_{P} \frac{\ln p}{p (p-1)} + o(\frac{1}{\ln n})$

And $H_n = \ln n +\gamma + O(\frac{1}{n})$, also $\sum \limits_{P} \sum \limits_{r=2}^{\infty} \frac{\ln p}{ p^r} = \sum \limits_{P} \frac{\ln p}{p (p-1)} $

With the limit $ n \to \infty$ we get that $ \sum \frac{1-\Lambda(k)}{k} = 2 \gamma$

Note : I think you are forced to use "PNT" by any way you approach the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Try the link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747769/is-this-valid-sum-n-1x-frac-lambda-leftn-rightn-sim-log-lef of more information

Answer (score -1):

See Xavier Gourdon and Pascal Sebah, "Collection of formulae for Euler's constant $\gamma$".